# Check if string exists in text file

Tags: java, txt

I'm trying to write a method, which checks if a given string exists in a .txt file, but it seems like my if/else statement isn't working correctly.

```
public void ChcekIfPasswordExsists(String check) throws FileNotFoundException{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Passwords.txt"));
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(reader);
    while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
        final String line = fileScanner.next();
        if(line.contains(check)){
            System.out.println("Password for " + check + " already exsits");
            break;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(check + " is usable");
            break;
        }        
    }
}
```

This is where I'm calling the method:

```
System.out.println("Enter the name of the app or website,\nwhere password is going to be use:");
useCase = s.nextLine();
 ChcekIfPasswordExsists(useCase);
```

I have looked at countless other posts with no effect. No matter what, it seems like the code skips the "if" statement and directly jumps to the "else" statement.

Comment: FYI there is a program called "GREP" (General Regular Expression Processor) that comes automatically installed on unix and mac computers. It is a souped up version of what you are trying to accomplish here, and the original intent was that other programs would use it for tasks like yours (it sends out its results via the standard process stream)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your `while` loop should be to iterate over all lines in the file until either you find a match or you hit the end of the file.  Consider this version:

```java
public void ChcekIfPasswordExsists(String check) throws FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Passwords.txt"));
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(reader);
    boolean flag = false;
    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String line = fileScanner.next();
        if (line.contains(check)) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag) {
        System.out.println("Password for " + check + " already exsits");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(check + " is usable");
    }
}
```

Also, I might be inclined to change the method signature to return a boolean value (true/false).  Based on that return value, you can display to the console the message you want.

Side note: If you are actually storing cleartext passwords in a text file, then stop doing that immediately.  It is a security hole.  Instead, setup a proper database and only store an irreversible hash of the passwords.

Comment: What if the input is "password" and there's "mypassword123" in the text file?  It would say already exists which is not true.

Comment: @ChengThao You might be right, but I suspect that this is a flat file with one password per line.  So, `String#contains` might be safe in this case.  The OP should clarify your point though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for the correction on the loop! However I seemed to have bumped into a new problem. How would I make so the code would end if the password exists and continue if not? I tried changing the method signature to return a boolean, but it throws an NoSuchElementException if I type a new name in the useCase string

Comment: My answer is already doing this.

Comment: @ChengThao You are correct. I illustrated that as a comment to the question. Unfortunately someone deleted that comment  It's perfectly easy to discover other's passwords that way (incremently).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was thinking when I call the method and have some code execute after the call. Tried with an if/else statement, where the method signature was changed to boolean, but it results in an exception